# OpenCV 3.1: calibrateCamera "assertion failed" - Raspberry Pi / Python

Tags: python, opencv

Morning!

I've read several other topics about this error, but none seem to quite apply. I'm learning about OpenCV and I don't usually program so please feel free to point out better resources and apologies if I've missed something.
I'm running OpenCV 3.1 and Python 2.7 on a Raspberry Pi 2 B running Jessie. I installed OpenCV according to [this article](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/) on pyimagesearch and it works fine otherwise.

I'm now trying to follow the calibrateCamera tutorial [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.html). I've gotten to the point where I can acquire and save all my images (or use the provided sample ones) and see the overlay generated, but when I reach the line with calibrateCamera, I get the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ni == ni1) in collectCalibrationData, file /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line 3064
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "findcorners.py", line 38, in 
>       ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
>   cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.1.0/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:3064: error: (-215) ni == ni1 in function collectCalibrationData

Below is the complete code I am using (currently testing on provided sample images):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30,     0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (8,6),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
       imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (7,6), corners2,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)


ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1], None, None)
np.savez("webcam_calibration_ouput", ret=ret, mtx=mtx, dist=dist, rvecs=rvecs, tvecs=tvecs)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: The assertion is telling you that they are not equal, but should be. Open the calibrateCamera code and search for the variables ni and ni1, see what they mean, why they need to be equivalent and why they aren't :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of Raspberry pi OpenCV error: (-215) ni == ni1 in function collectCalibrationData

](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43795220/raspberry-pi-opencv-error-215-ni-ni1-in-function-collectcalibrationdata/45018585#45018585)