# Raspberry pi OpenCV error: (-215) ni == ni1 in function collectCalibrationData

Tags: python, opencv

I'm running python 3 on a raspberry pi 3 and have opencv installed. I took 10 images of a checkerboard, it detects all 10 images and displays them, but when it gets to the last line, it throws an error. Here's the images i used: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtGLf.jpg This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob

# termination criteria
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 30, 0.001)

# prepare object points, like (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (2,0,0) ....,(6,5,0)
objp = np.zeros((6*7,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:7,0:6].T.reshape(-1,2)

# Arrays to store object points and image points from all the images.
objpoints = [] # 3d point in real world space
imgpoints = [] # 2d points in image plane.

images = glob.glob('*.jpg')

for fname in images:
    print('test')
    img = cv2.imread(fname)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Find the chess board corners
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray, (6,9),None)

    # If found, add object points, image points (after refining them)
    if ret == True:
        print('test2')
        objpoints.append(objp)

        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11),(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)

        # Draw and display the corners
        img = cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img, (6,9), corners2,ret)
        cv2.imshow('img',img)
        cv2.waitKey(500)
print('test3')
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints, imgpoints, gray.shape[::-1],None,None)
```

Answer (score 3):

the example assumes that you have a 6x7 chessboard image, i think you have a 6x9. 
you have to prepare the objp variable for a 6x9 calibration image, so the code has to be like this: objp = np.zeros((**6*9**,3), np.float32)

code:

```
objp = np.zeros((6*9,3), np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Rui Sebastiao.
I was using 14 x 10 so I changed the following lines and at least no error :)

```
    objp = np.zeros((14*10, 3), np.float32)
    objp[:, :2] = np.mgrid[0:14, 0:10].T.reshape(-1, 2)
```